# cycle/tween colors while element is tapped

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to tween / cycle the color of the background of a page while it is clicked. 
When the click is lifted, the cycling stops and the background color remains at the last cycled value. When it is clicked again, the process will continue.

Check the example here to see what I am referring to when I say cycle the color http://www.javascript-fx.com/development/colorcycle/spancycle.html

While browsing for solutions I have come across some libraries like JSTween or GSAP, but with my very fragile javascript experience I failed at implementing the examples to suit my need.

Any suggestions on how to do this will be helpful, preferably without any libraries since it will aid more in my understanding of javascript. 
I am not looking for exact code, a pseudocode explanation of the process will also be great.

Best,
Andrei

Comment: The last paragraph makes it sound like you really want to learn - would you might saying what have you tried and where you're stuck? Any code attempts (post them here) would be nice. Stack Overflow works best when we know what you've attempted, it makes our attempts to aid you much better guided. Do you know how to detect a click? Detecting a second click? Detect when the click is lifted? Change the background color? Cycle between different choices? Do the smooth transition in colors? Wrapping it all together?

Answer (score 0):

So, Tweening colors is pretty easy with TweenJS or TweenMax (or TweenLite).  I'll show this using TweenMax, mostly because the pseudocode is hard when there is no logic to pseudocode.  Assume you have a text element:

```
<p id="text">This is some text to colorize</p>
```

You can tween the color of the text to red (`#f00`) over two seconds like this:

```
var textEl = document.getElementById('text');
TweenMax.to(textEl, 2, {color: '#f00'});
```

As far as cycling goes, you can send an `onComplete` handler to the tween, which will fire when the tween finishes.  This will cause it to cycle between red and black:

```
var textEl = document.getElementById('text');

function toRed() {
  TweenMax.to(textEl, 2, {color: '#f00', onComplete: toBlack});
}

function toBlack() {
  TweenMax.to(textEl, 2, {color: '#000', onComplete: toRed});
}

toRed();
```

Here is a CodePen [showing this in action](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/Gcyqp).

If you want to make this a bit more compact, you can cycle by flipping the `colorFrom` and `colorTo`:

```
function cycle(colorFrom, colorTo) {
  TweenMax.to(textEl, 2, {color: colorTo, onComplete: function() {
      cycle(colorTo, colorFrom);
  }});
}

cycle('#000', '#F00');
```

Doing the same thing in other tweening libraries becomes VERY similar.

Pseudocode for doing this cycle while tapped might be like this:

```
ON_CLICK:
  ShowCycle = !ShowCycle;
  IF ShowCycle
    TweenHandle = cycle( RED, BLACK )
  ELSE
    IF EXISTS TweenHandle
      cancelCycle( TweenHandle )
      TweenHandle = null
    END IF
  END IF
```